# Why BFS signs nodes with 2 colors, and DFS with 3 colors?

Tags: algorithm, graph, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

It has suddenly occured into my mind.

Why do we use only 2 colors in BFS graphs traveral

and 3 are needed for DFS ?

for instance: from wikipedia:

BFS:

```
procedure BFS(G,v):
2      create a queue Q
3      enqueue v onto Q
4      mark v
5      while Q is not empty:
6          t ← Q.dequeue()
7          if t is what we are looking for:
8              return t
9          for all edges e in G.adjacentEdges(t) do
12             u ← G.adjacentVertex(t,e)
13             if u is not marked:
14                  **mark u**
15                  enqueue u onto Q
16     return none
```

DFS:

```
  procedure DFS(G,v):
2      label v **as explored**
3      for all edges e in G.adjacentEdges(v) do
4          if edge e is unexplored then
5              w ← G.adjacentVertex(v,e)
6              if vertex w is unexplored then
7                  label e as a **discovery edge**
8                  recursively call DFS(G,w)
9              else
10                 label e as a **back edge**
```

why are 2 colors not enough for DFS?
why are 3 colors reduant for BFS?

here is another BFS (this time 3 colors):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a different number of colors in each of the two algorithms because they are used to represent fundamentally different types of information.

In both BFS and DFS, nodes need to be marked as either unexplored nodes or explored nodes.  Two colors are needed at a minimum to represent this information.

In the DFS implementation you have listed above, the implementation also uses colors to classify edges as either "discovery edges" (edges that form the depth-first search tree produced by the algorithm) or "back edges" (edges that move from a deeper part of the DFS tree to a shallower part of the DFS tree).  These colors are used to color edges, not nodes.  As a result, three colors are necessary for edges - unexplored edges, "discovery" edges, and back edges.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I have added example of BFS with 3 colors. Why is this needed? Why do we need to clasify edges?

Comment: @EladBenda- All of this depends on the application.  There is no fundamental reason why you *must* classify edges, and often you don't need to.  Some implementations might use three colors in BFS to distinguish between unvisited, visited-but-not-yet-expanded, and visited-and-expanded.  I honestly think this isn't worth worrying about.  It purely depends on what you want to do with the search, and is not some fundamental characteristic of the algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

There can be applications of BFS where we'd need 3 colors for the nodes as well. A simple example is to print *each* vertex and edge of an undirected graph *just once* using BFS. We cannot do that with just 2 colors. To see why that is, let's think about the status of the vertex that's sitting at the other end of the edge we're currently exploring (for an iteration). The vertex at the other end can be (a) already processed (b) not yet discovered (c) already sitting in the queue, waiting to be processed. If it's (a), we have already seen the current edge before, so we don't need to print it again. For (b) and (c), we're seeing it for the first time and we need to print it. Ok, good enough. So, we decide to use just one flag, `visited`, which would be `true` for (a) and `false` for (b) and (c), so that we can decide when to print an edge and when not to. But, as a consequence, we just established that we'd need to keep the `visited` flag `false` for the vertices sitting in the queue, i.e. case (c). So, we won't be able to mark it when pushing onto the queue. We can mark it only when we explored all edges connected to it. As a consequence, when facing case (c) in an iteration, we won't be able to tell whether the vertex at the other end is already on the queue or not (unless we explicitly search the queue). We'd end up pushing it onto the queue again and end up with a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

If we explain this in simple words, in BFS once we have visited an node it implies that all its neighbors are visited as well and we need not to visit that vertex again. 
But in DFS, there is an operation called Backtracking which implies that we may need to visit an already visited node again and all its neighbors are not visited at once so having a third color grey acknowledges the fact that, "Yes! it has been visited and you do not need to print it but there are neighbors to this node which are still not visited"